# Is there a name for high risk / high returns debt funds in India?

Tags: india, mutual-funds, debt, risk

I'm looking for debt funds in India that aim to give you high returns, at the cost of high risk. Is there a name for such a category of funds?

I found one example of such a fund, Franklin India Income Builder Fund, but is there a name for such a category of funds?

I don't want to specify a particular duration or type of bonds that the fund should buy, or the strategy that used to generate returns — I want to leave those decisions to the fund manager. All I care about is high risk / high return. Is there a name for such funds?

Answer (score 1):

> debt funds in India that aim to give you high returns, at the cost of high risk

This is what is generally termed **high yield** debt funds.

They will be more volatile than lower-risk debt funds, but can be expected to have a greater return. Some high-yield bonds can even have a return not that far below what you could expect to see in the stock market, at a not-insignificant risk of one or more of the companies in the mix declaring partial or full bankruptcy.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't a category of funds — I see categories like corporate bond, gilt, arbitrage, etc. But these categories of fund limit themselves to certain types of bonds or certain strategies, which I don't want to limit myself to. There seems to be no name to indicate "high returns, high risk".

Comment: @VaddadiKartick Generally, the name for what you are looking for **is** "high yield". If your bank doesn't offer that as a searchable category, you will have to search by some other means. Try sorting by 12-month return descending, for example. But ultimately, that is a question for your bank (or wherever you have your investment account).